# Getting an error to override onConnectedToMaster() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have extended "MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks" to my class but still getting the override error. Unity version: 2021.3 and Photon Pun 2.

Error message

> Assets\connectToServer.cs(15,26): error CS0115: 'connectToServer.onConnectedToMaster()': no suitable method found to override

[Image of Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckC79.png)

Comment: Casing matters in c#.  `OnConnectedToMaster`.  You should add the code as text so everyone can access it.

Comment: Silly me! I don't know how did I miss that. Thank you so much

Comment: You have a typo, `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` class has `OnConnectedToMaster ()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.